# My color in XML not reflecting in actual layout

Tags: android, xml, colors, android-cardview

My XML Looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/blackboard"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scroll_view_qr_lost">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="#ccc"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#222"
                    android:hint="Type School Name * "
                    android:id="@+id/school_name_activity_lost_qr"
                    android:textColorHint="#6d0d"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="#ccc"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#222"

                    android:hint="Type Student's Name * "
                    android:id="@+id/student_name_activity_lost_qr"
                    android:textColorHint="#6d0d"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="#ccc"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:textColor="#222"
                    android:hint="Type Student's Class * "
                    android:id="@+id/class_no_activity_lost_qr"
                    android:textColorHint="#6d0d"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="#000"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Type Section (If any)  "
                    android:textColor="#222"
                    android:id="@+id/student_section_activity_lost_qr"
                    android:textColorHint="#6d0d"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:background="#ccc"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:hint="Type Student's Roll No * "
                    android:id="@+id/student_roll_no_activity_lost_qr"
                    android:textColorHint="#6d0d"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="#222"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="* fields must be entered,  \nPlease press the blue floating button to submit. "
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:textColor="#ccc"/>

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab_submit_lost_qr_application"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryii"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And my screen was supposed to look like this .
[image: This is the screen generated by the IDE and it should look like this in real]

But my actual screen in device looks like this ,

[image]

so can anyone suggest  what is going wrong with my program?

**P.S. the colors were working perfectly fine earlier.**

Comment: Since you wrote `android:background="#ccc"` in CardView, won't it be the expected color? Try changing it into `android:background="#ffffff"`

Comment: no #ccc is a color which is white but not so absolute white as #ffffff

Comment: ah okay. another thing that i can think of, did you change any style or theme?

Comment: No even if i do i have overridden the colors in the xml by specifying color as #ccc is not it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the CardView uses a different attribute to set the background color.

Try using app:cardBackgroundColor="#ccc"

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the app tools for the card view, so just change **app:cardbackgroundcolor="#ccc"** instead of **android:background="#ccc"**

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#ccc"
```

Remember to declare:

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```